# Нужна помощь с использованием API

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Вот в чем проблема:
Есть git, есть API, есть приложение. Я ещё начинающий и не могу понять как правильно использовать API. Есть уже настроенная форма пасспорта где описаны все апи и используются для регистрации и тп. Мне нужно уже в другой форме использовать те же апи для получения инф о юзере.

Возможно не совсем понятно объяснил, но буду что нужно добавлять.

Вот моя задача, возможно это поможет:
При нажатии на кнопку Фейсбука нужно от сервера запросить аккаунты пользователя (GetUserAccounts) если среди них нет фейсбука, то открывать диалог, который ты сейчас сделал. Если все хорошо и ты получил токен фейсбука, то нужно его сохранить в базе (AddUserAccount).
Актуальное описание АПИ можно смотреть http://54.235.126.255/thrifts/

Comment: а в чем помощь то нужна?

Comment: видимо в том, что бы понять задание.

Comment: Я вроде знаю, но мне ник не нравится. Извините, настроение плохое.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что у тебя должен быть менеджер UserAccount, в котором есть какое либо перечисление, например enum, в котором прописаны vkontakte, facebook, twitter, и т.д.
Ты проходишь по списку, если после проверки на facebook возвращает false, то "открывать диалог, который ты сейчас сделал" (хз что это такое), если же все хорошо("получил токен фейсбука" читаем доку по ФБ), то вызываешь метод (AddUserAccount), который сохраняет новый (UserAccount). Чтобы использовать информацию "в другой форме" нужно добавить в "в другой форме" делегат UserAccount, и потом по его свойствам(прописаны в твоей ссылке http://54.235.126.255/thrifts/) считывать эту информацию.

П.С. ник внатуренеочень.